# Calling main thread from a task in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8

I have a code

```
async Task<String> RunAsync()
{
     using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
         // Doing some Work without blocking UI.
         // Here i want to call my main thread delegate function
         del(jsonString);
    }
}
```

I want to call the delegate function in main thread. I tried Dispatcher but there is no Dispatcher Class. How would i do that in windows phone 8.1 sdk

Comment: where is json string coming from? the client?

Comment: from web api, the task i am running before del function. i just need to call del(jsonstr) function in main thread because it will contain UI Elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the Dispatcher of the CoreWindows from anywhere in your application like so:

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () => {

    //call main thread here
});
```

Keep in mind, that calling the main thread takes some time (up to half a second on my Nokia Lumia 635). So if for instance if you have loops, do not use `Dispatcher.RunAsync()` in each iteration.